# How to find the number of common characters in two strings c++

Tags: c++, string, for-loop, char, compare

If string 1 and string 2 are equal sizes, how would we find the num of common characters and store into some int?

For example:

```
string A = "abcdabc"
string B = "cabzabc"
```

The common number of characters is 6 out of 7 (count duplicates).

so far I have:

```
int count = 0;

for(int I = 0; I < A.size(); I++)
{
    if(A[I] == B[I]
    {
       count++;
     }
}
```

but when I output count its = 0.

EDIT: got it to work guys, something was wrong with my initialized string but now its fine! Thanks.

Comment: I think your bug is somewhere else. You may need to use your debugger to see what happens to ` count`.

Comment: Recommendation: step through the program with the debugging utility that should have come with your compiler (and if one didn't come with your compiler, strongly consider getting a different set of tools) and keep an eye on `count`.

Comment: Though your logic is incorrect to find out common number of characters between two string but, still, with the given input it should give output `3` and not `0` (look at the last `3` characters of both the string). Please post the MCVE.

Answer (score 1):

What you are currently counting is whether those two char arrays have same character on a certain index. This is obviously not what you wish for.
Some options: 
1. create map and store number of occurrences of each letter, then compare afterwards
2. iterate trough one array, and for each character there, iterate trough complete other array and count occurrences
3. sort these arrays in alphabetical order and you'll see how many times each letter occurs in each of them

EDIT: Let's run trough your code:

```
I = 0; A[I] = 'a'; B[I] = 'c' //are they the same? count = 0
I = 1; A[I] = 'b'; B[I] = 'a' //are they the same? count = 0
I = 2; A[I] = 'c'; B[I] = 'b' //are they the same? count = 0
I = 3; A[I] = 'd'; B[I] = 'z' //are they the same? count = 0
I = 4; A[I] = 'a'; B[I] = 'a' //are they the same? count = 1
I = 5; A[I] = 'b'; B[I] = 'b' //are they the same? count = 2
I = 6; A[I] = 'c'; B[I] = 'c' //are they the same? count = 3
```

Comment: I got it to work, the code was correct, something with my string was the issue!